# Google App Engine Java - javax.servlet source files

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Using Eclipse (juno) and GAE plugin, I've compiled and ran the "guestbook" example (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating) without any problem.
Both of the class of the example extend "HttpServlet" class of javax.servlet.http package.

I'd like to see the source code (and javadoc) of this class and of the other class of the package (and super package), but I can't figure out where they are.

They are not in
Program Files\eclipse-jee-juno-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\src
(I've tried all of the files in there)

Binary files should be in servlet-api.jar in
Program Files\eclipse-jee-juno-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0\lib\shared

I've googled a lot without success.
Anybody knows where to find sources of javax.servlet package?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sources for `javax` classes are included with Java EE distributions and not the App Engine SDK. If you can't find a local Java EE distribution, you can try downloading the sources [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/geronimo/specs/trunk/geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec/src/main/java/), and referencing them from within Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw that it should be in the EE distribution, so I installed it (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html) but it didn't help (in the GlassFish folders there are no source codes and the java folder is unchanged after the installation of the EE version). I was looking for a jar or zip file to attach in Eclipse. (Note: I'm a total newbie in java web, till now I developed only small offline (java) programs (college courses level)).

Comment: You should be able to do an svn checkout on https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/geronimo/specs/trunk/geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec/ to get the complete file set.

Answer (score 0):

Project properties -> configure build path -> libraries -> drop down arrow of App Engine SDK-> drop down arrow of servlet-api.jar -> click javadoc location -> click edit -> enter javadoc URL : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/